# What's the difference between Info.plist and [app name]-Info.plist?

Tags: xcode, info.plist

Everything I read online talks about Info.plist. XCode made me a [name of the app]-Info.plist file when I created the project, and it seems to have the same keys in it as sample Info.plist s I see online. Is it fine if I keep it's name or should I rename it to Info.plist?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, they are the same. When Apple released iOS SDK 3.2 (or around there), new projects created [App-Name]-Info.plist instead of the older Info.plist. If you only have one target in your project, you can rename it back, but it's personal preference.

Comment: The important point is that Xcode copies the file from whatever name it's under in the source to Info.plist in the product, so the name is only different for the file you have among your source code. The file in the built product is always Info.plist.